# How to show paragraph text with JavaScript including <p> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, paragraph

i`m new with JavaScript and reactjs . i have a text that contain some paragraph tags like

newline and ... from a textarea with CKEDITOR. how can i show saved text in a html tag? for example i want to show this text :

```html
myString=<p>Cumque et blanditiis magnam optio amet. Eum eos et et et sit autem optio. Asperiores fuga iure quis sequi voluptas laboriosam et.</p>
<div className={'myclass'}>myString</div>
```

in a html tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of cleaning a string of its html tags or other malicious javascript code is called sanitization.

One method is to use reactjs's

**dangerouslySetInnerHTML**

> dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in
>   the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because
>   it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting
>   (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have
>   to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html
>   key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous. For example:

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

But I will recomend using libraries like [DomPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) or [SanitizeHtmlReact](https://github.com/zacharystenger/sanitize-html-react)

because they are more flexible and has many options.

Check their examples and demos for more info

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) :

```
<div className={'myclass'} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: myString}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, we can write a method to accept String and replace HTML special character to like

```
var charMap ={
 '<' : '&lt; ',
 '>' : '&gt'
 }`
```